# Trigger PHP methods without a page reload

Tags: php, ajax

At the moment my methods work using GET requests:

```
http://localhost/intranet2/?break_start
http://localhost/intranet2/?break_end
```

I want to acheive similar results only using Ajax and jQuery. I've tried:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
        },
    hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
        }
});
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
});

$.ajax({
 url: "http://localhost/intranet2/?page=break_start",
 context: document.body
 }).done(function(data) {
     alert(data);
     $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        });

 });



});
</script>
```

My trigger elements is:

```
<button id="opener">Start Break</button>
```

My modal window opens successfully but my PHP method to update the database via the URL

```
http://localhost/intranet2/?break_start
```

fails to trigger? Help.

Comment: Is the modal created dynamicly? Is the button actually bound to the event?

Comment: You should not use a `GET` to perform a database update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( "#opener" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

When using a button, you need to keep the page from performing it's default action of reloading. That's what the `e.preventDefault()` method does.

You can read about it [here on the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: I replaced both instances of the code above into my code but the PHP scripts fail to execute?

Comment: @DevishOne. There don't appear to be any. From the console:
 
200 OK 2ms, but my database doesn't get updated?

Comment: I did manage to get it working using you're code, hence +1. Thanks.